# Cannot drop existing index

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

Service I'm using is DB2 on cloud.

I have created an index but didn't specify the schema

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_TAB1      
ON SCHEMA1.TAB1 (RECLASS_MONTH DESC)
;
```

It was created in the following INDSCHEMA

```
SELECT * FROM syscat.indexes 
    WHERE TABNAME  ='TAB1'
```

| INDSCHEMA | INDNAME | TABSCHMA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 506TEFMHSB | IDX_TAB1 | SCHEMA1 |

I want to drop it and specify the schema,
however running the following DROP sql gives me error

```
DROP INDEX "506TEFMHSB".IDX_TAB1
; 

Error message
"506TEFMHSB.IDX_TAB1" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.27.25
```

Or

```
DROP INDEX IDX_TAB1
;

Error message
"506TEFMHSB.IDX_TAB1" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.27.25
```

Not sure how I'm supposed to drop this, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is schema1 (as shown in your question) different in any way from 506TEFMHSB, and also, are you connecting to the database as user 506TEFMHSB ?

Comment: Yes schema1 is a different schema so the TABSCHEMA = 'SCHEMA1' while INDSCHEMA = '506TEFMHSB'

I am connecting to the db via the cloud console using a corporate account, not sure what user is the engine using. Running 'SELECT CURRENT_USER from sysibm.sysdummy1;' gives me '506TEFMHSB' so I assume somehow I am logged in as that user

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this worked for some reason

```
DROP INDEX "506TEFMHSB".IDX_COGNOS_COMPLIANCE_DASHBOARD_DATA     ;
```

I'm not sure whether there was some issue with the fact that I used newline between the end of the statement and the semicolon and the whitespace inbetween...but the issue is solved